# AndEngine: Resizing sprite's contact boundaries

Tags: android, andengine

Sprites are composed of Sprite and Body class. Sprite class handles sprite's "look" and body handles it's physics (touch boundaries among other things).

The problem is I can scale sprite by calling setScale(). But that doesn't scale it's body.

Simple Example:

```
    sprite = new Sprite(x, y, mTextureRegion, mObjectManager);
    sprite.setScale(2); //scales sprite at 2

    //since sprite is scaled at 2, body will also be scaled at 2
    body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld, sprite, DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);

    face.setScale(3); //scales ONLY sprite, body doesn't get scaled
    //sprite size is scaled at 3 but it's body (boundaries) are still scaled at 2
```

Is there a way to scale sprite's body?

Comment: You can't do that, sorry. Workaround is: destroy body, and then set another one with new size.

Comment: @Łukasz Is there a way to extend the body class and add resize function?

Comment: Not sure, never tried, but you can make a simple method that destroys and attaches new body, still you would have to consider how often do you need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach your `Body` after scaling your `sprite`.
if you want to resize the `sprite` again, unregister the `registerPhysicsConnector`
and scale the `sprite` then connect sprite and body again.
Hope it works..!